# Make jquery validation on javascript functions - change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me make jquery validation on a javascript function. basically it change the UI whenever you choose one of the accounts on a dropdown menu: I want to check that one of them in the checkbox was selected to display "you need to check one of them"

```
$("#selectAcc").change(function() {
    var type = $("#selectAcc option:selected").text();

    $("#accountInfo").empty();

    if (type === "Saving Account") {
        $("#accountInfo").append("<label>Rate: </label><input type='text' name='rate'><br>");
        $("#accountInfo").append("<input type='checkbox' name='days' value='90' id='90'/>90 days<br>");
        $("#accountInfo").append("<input type='checkbox' name='days' value='180' id='180'/>180 days<br>");
        $("#accountInfo").append("<input type='checkbox' name='days' value='360' id='360'/>360 days<br>"); 


        $("input:checkbox").click(function() {

            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
                $(group).prop("checked", false);
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I don't see any major issues with the code. You might want to use a radio group instead of checkboxes though, since the many name="days" might cause problems. Are you trying to display a message "you need to check one of them" and hide the message when a checkbox is checked?

Comment: Are you hoping to use the jQuery Validation Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to count the checkboxes that are checked based on a grouping by the name attribute this might help you:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
  var clicked_count = $('input:checkbox[name="'+$(this).attr("name")+'"]:checked').length;
  console.log( clicked_count + " checkboxes are checked" );
});
```

So you might display "you need to check one of them" when the result of this is 0.

Answer (score 0):

connect the listener to an element that isnt added after dom.

```
$("#accountInfo").on('click', 'input', function(){
      // do something

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with radio button instead? Something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Ab3z/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ab3z/)

Or if you are checking is there any checkbox checked;

```
 $("#selectAcc").change(function() { 
var checked=0;
    $( "input:checkbox" ).each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
        checked++;
        }
});
    if(checked==0){
    alert('Please check days!');
    }

});
```